# How to check if erc is running

Tags: erc, irc

I want to write a function that does one thing if erc is running and starts erc (using command `erc`) if not.

I tried to write it myself, but I couldn't find out how to check if erc is running. How can I do this in elisp?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I did so, thank you @Drew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects: is there an `erc` process running in the buffer? and if there is such a process, is there an established network connection to the server?

If you look in `erc.el`, you will see how `erc` itself determines the process status to add to the mode line (line 6438 in the file):

```
    ...
    (let (       ...
          (process-status (cond ((and (erc-server-process-alive)
                                      (not erc-server-connected))
                                 ":connecting")
                                ((erc-server-process-alive)
                                 "")
                                (t
                                 ": CLOSED")))
```

IOW, it uses the function `erc-server-process-alive` to check whether the process is alive and the value of the variable `erc-server-connected` to see if it is connected to the server: if it is alive but not connected to the server, it reports "connecting"; else if it is alive, it reports nothing (i.e. everything is good); else it reports "CLOSED".

You should check the doc strings of the function above (`C-h f erc-server-process-alive`) and the variable (`C-h v erc-server-connected`) and read them carefully, but this should allow you to determine the state of `erc`.

Comment: Very helpfull, thank you. (erc-server-connected) gives me what I want, My function now looks like this: (defun erc-start-or-cycle ()
  "if erc is already running, go to the next channel. Else, start erc."
  (interactive)
  (if (erc-server-connected)
  (erc-next-channel-buffer)
    (erc)))

Comment: `erc-server-connected` is a variable, not a function, so that should read: `(if erc-server-connected ...)` with no parens (unless you have defined your own `erc-server-connected` function). It might be possible for the value of the variable to be `t`, but the process might have died (I don't know if that's possilble, but it is at least a theoretical possibility): it would behoove you to check the state of the process as well IMO.